# Elementary number theory on congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Let the numbers $c_i$ be defined by the power series identity 
$(1+ x + x^2+ ... + x^n)/(1-x)^{p-1} = 1 + c_1x + c_2x^2+... $. Show that $c_i \equiv 0 \bmod{p}$ for all $i \geq 1$

Any help on starting out, please? Thank u!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Since for all suitable $x$ we have $1+x+\cdots+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$, we are looking at 
$$\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^p}.$$
Now write down the power series expansion of $\frac{1}{(1-x)^p}$.

**Remark:** Note however that in general we do not have $c_i\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. Try for example $\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^2}$ (so $n=1$, $p=3$). But for suitable values of $n$, the result holds.

Comment: oh damn! sorry, i forgot to write down the work I've already done. sorry, worked on this three days ago and forgot...

Comment: If you had reached this far, I can delete. It really puts one quite close.

Comment: yes, i had done that part. sorry, my internet is being very inconsistent T_T i'm having trouble editing and posting

Comment: $1+px+(p^2+p)x^2/2+(p^3+3p^2+2p)x^3/6+...$ right?

Comment: actually i see now! i had done a calculation mistake and hadnt gotten the exact expression as above. thats why it didnt made sense!